# How to add custom Models Rocket Chat

Tags: rocket.chat

I am trying to add new models to RocketChat specifically to store Location information. I have extended the `models._Base model` to `ModelLocations` and assigned it to `RocketChat.models.Locations` as following

```
RocketChat.models.Locations = new ModelLocations('location', true);
```

But when I try to use `RocketChat.models.Locations` it's always undefined. I observed the migrations folder and thought I need to create a migration file but I couldn't find documentation for that. Can anybody point me on how to add a new model.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add the new model's file path in `Rocket.Chat/packages/rocketchat-lib/package.js`. Once added it works.